# macOS Photo app deleted photos

Tags: macos, photos

I upgraded my 21,5” 2011 iMac with an ssd replacing the combo drive.

I booted up from the ssd, navigated through my harddrive to my home folder of my old install, and double clicked on my photo library.

Photos then said the library needed repair and I let it do its thing overnight.

I came back this morning and 90% of my photos and albums are gone

Anyone experienced anything like this? What should I do? Photorec or other data recovery? or can this still be fixed? Photos does not give me an error when opening, nor did it ever warn it was going to delete stuff

Comment: The simple method, of course, is to simply restore them from your backup. No backup, then 1) lesson learned & 2) whatever data recovery software you can lay your hands on. Why was your Photos lib still on your old drive anyway? How old was it? What version of Photos? Do you use iCloud? Did you upgrade your OS at the same time as install the new drive? There's a lot of detail missing from your method.

Comment: I installed an ssd in the combo drive bay, so the original HD remains installed.

I only have 128gb ssd and 200gb photo library so I could not copy it over.

I don’t use iCloud, I was already running high Sierra 10.13.6 and I installed that too on the ssd using the latest installer from the App Store. 

I’ve done this numerous times in the past, just copy the library and double click to open. I didn’t have enough room so I just openend it directly from the old drive. It’s a healthy drive (replaced the original 1,5y ago) so I wasn’t too worried (same os, same pc, same username,...)